# How to make a scene game in a single view appliaction and with a regual viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode7

How do you make a game like geometry dash, were the developers have planned the scenes and stuff? Not like flappy bird, because in flappy bird, the game moves the pipes to random positons. I want to make the whole game with placing the images where i want them and stuff. But i cant make a big game in just a viewcontroller. I know i can make them in scenekit, but is there anyways i can do this in a normal viewcontroller?

I know there will be haters disliking this comment because there is no code, but if that makes you feel better, have a nice day!:D But i dont really see how my codes can explain what i want here:)

PLEASE HELP :)

Comment: There will be many who doesn't know what  geometry dash is. You could give a link to it so that we don't have to search for it.  Your question is too broad. What do you mean by big game ? The only thing I see in your question is to place the images at random positions. Is it what you need ?

Comment: Hello thanks for reply!:) Yes i want to place images at random positions (myself) Not via code. Its really hard to explain :/ Do you have a ios device?:) And in a viewcontroller there is just limited space on how much images you can fit on the screen if you know what i mean. I want to be able to make the view bigger so i can plan the whole game and place the images where i want them to be. Sorry for bad spelling, im Norwegian.